# Cannot log after tests are done in jestjs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have written test cases for signin API using jest. After completing all five test of a test suit jest give me following error in log.

Can any body tell Why it is So and how to fix it?

**CODE:(signup.test.ts)**

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import { TYPES } from '../src/inversify.types'
import { Application } from '../src/app/Application'
import { container } from '../src/inversify.config'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { RESPONSE_CODE } from '../src/utils/enums/ResponseCode'
import { RESPONSE_MESSAGES } from '../src/utils/enums/ResponseMessages'
import { UserSchema } from '../src/components/user/User';
// import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
var application: Application

describe("POST / - SIGNUP endpoint", () => {
    // var testusers: any;
    //This hook is executed before running all test cases, It will make application instance, make it to listen 
    // on it on port 3000 and add test document in DB
    beforeAll(async () => {
        // Make enviroment variables available throughout the application
        dotenv.config();
        // Getting application instance using iversify container
        application = container.get<Application>(TYPES.Application);
        // Initialize frontside of application
        await application.bootstrap();
        // Starting Application server on given port
        await application.listen(3000);
    });

    afterAll(
        //This hook is executed after running all test cases and delete test document in database
        async () =>{
        const res = await UserSchema.deleteMany({ Name: { $in: [ "Test User", "Test" ] } });
        // `0` if no docs matched the filter, number of docs deleted otherwise
        console.log('---------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', (res as any).deletedCount);
    }
    )

    it("Signup for user that don\'t exists", async () => {
        const response = await request(application.getServer()).post('/user/signup')
        .send({
            "Email": JSON.parse(process.env.TEST_USER).Email,
            "Name": "Test User",
            "Password": process.env.TEST_ACCOUNTS_PASSWORD
            })
            expect(response.status).toBe(RESPONSE_CODE.CREATED);
            expect(JSON.parse(response.text)).toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ 
                Message: RESPONSE_MESSAGES.ADDED_SUCESSFULLY, 
                Data: expect.objectContaining({
                    Name: 'Test User',
                    Country: '',
                    PhoneNumber: '',
                    // Password: '$2b$10$nIHLW/SA73XLHoIcND27iuODFAArOvpch6FL/eikKT78qbShAl6ry',
                    Dob: '',
                    Role: 'MEMBER',
                    IsEmailVerified: false,
                    IsBlocked: 'ACTIVE',
                    IsTokenSent: false,
                    twoFAStatus: false,
                    // _id: '5c812e2715e0711b98260fee',
                    Email: JSON.parse(process.env.TEST_USER).Email
                })
            })
            );
        console.log('*** Signup for user that don\'t exists *** response', response.text, 'response status', response.status);   
    });
    it("Signup for user that exists", async () => {
        const response = await request(application.getServer()).post('/user/signup')
        .send({
            "Email": JSON.parse(process.env.TEST_USER).Email,
            "Name": "Test User",
            "Password": process.env.TEST_ACCOUNTS_PASSWORD
            })
            expect(response.status).toBe(RESPONSE_CODE.CONFLICT);
            expect(JSON.parse(response.text)).toEqual({ 
                Message: RESPONSE_MESSAGES.ALREADY_EXISTS
            })
        console.log('*** Signup for user that don\'t exists *** response', response.text, 'response status', response.status);   
    });

});
```

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
>   stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
>   `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
>
> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
>   async in your test?

```
Attempted to log "{ accepted: [ 'unverifiedtestuser@abc.com' ],
      rejected: [],
      envelopeTime: 621,
      messageTime: 867,
      messageSize: 906,
      response: '250 2.0.0 OK  1551945300 f6sm5442066wrt.87 - gsmtp',
      envelope:
       { from: 'abc@gmail.com',
         to: [ 'unverifiedtestuser@abc.com' ] },
      messageId: '<45468449-b5c8-0d86-9404-d55bb5f4g6a3@gmail.com>' }".




at CustomConsole.log (node_modules/jest-util/build/CustomConsole.js:156:10)
  at src/email/MailHandler.ts:2599:17
  at transporter.send.args (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:226:21)
  at connection.send (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:247:32)
  at callback (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:435:13)
  at stream._createSendStream (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:458:24)
  at SMTPConnection._actionSMTPStream (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1481:20)
  at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:968:22)
  at SMTPConnection._processResponse (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:764:20)
  at SMTPConnection._onData (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:570:14)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the test itself? It will help to diagnose what is happening. Here is a [Jest async example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.html) and an [example GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7287) to give you some idea of things that can cause this type of error.

Comment: @ty2k. I have updated the code plz check. I have already checkout out docs but unable to figure out

Comment: Check out the [Callbacks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#callbacks) section in Jest's async documentation, specifically the section that passes `done` as an argument. There's also this [post in a Supertest issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/437#issuecomment-348641299) that has the same sort of problem as you. Basically, your tests are completing before your server is shut down.

Answer (score 17):

I was using the react-native default test case (see below) when `Cannot log after tests are done` happened.

```js
it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Apparently, the problem was that the test ended but logging was still needed. So I tried to make the callback in the test case async, hoping that the test won't terminate immediately:

```js
it('renders correctly', async () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

And it worked. However, I have very little clue what the inner working is.

Comment: Sadly not works for me!
Note: In App.js I just render Navigation component Config "NavigationContainer"

Answer (score 14):

If you are using async/await type in your code, then this error can occur when you are calling `async` function without `await` keyword.

In my case, I have defined a function like this below,

```
async getStatistics(headers) {
    ....
    ....
    return response;
}
```

But I have called this method like `getStatistics(headers)` instead of `await getStatistics(headers)`.

When I included `await`, it worked fine and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 9):

In my case while using **nodejs + jest + supertest** the problem was that when I `import app from "./app"` to my test file to do some stuff with supertest (`request(app)`), I actually import with `app.listen()` , because when I'm exporting `app`, export takes in account `app.listen()` too, but we don't need `app.listen()` in tests and it throws an error

> "Cannot log after tests are done.Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?"

**Here is all in one file(that's the problem!)**

```js
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// ROUTES
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to Blog API!" });
});

app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/api/blogs", blogsRouter);

// The server will start only if the connection to database is established
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MongoDB est connecté");

        const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The server is running on port: ${port}`));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

export default app;
```

**To solve this issue I created 2 separate folders:**

**// 1) app.ts**

Where I put all stuff for my `const app = express()`, routes etc and export app

```js
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

// ROUTES
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to Blog API!" });
});

app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/api/blogs", blogsRouter);

export default app;
```

**// 2) index.ts**

Where I put `app.listen() and mongoose.connection()` and import `app`

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import app from "./app";

// The server will start only if the connection to database is established

mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MongoDB est connecté");

        const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The server is running on port: ${port}`));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gHEv5iNRKk&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge). 
at the 32 minute he explain the problem

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me because I had an infinite loop `while (true)`. In my case, I was able to add a method for setting the value of the loop based on user input, rather than defaulting to true.

Answer (score 2):

For me I needed to add an `await` before the `expect()` call also to stop this error (and an `async` before the `test()` callback function).

Also caused and fixed Jest not detecting coverage on the lines in the code throwing the error!

```js
test("expect error to be thrown for incorrect request", async () => {
  await expect(
  // ^ added this
    async () => await getData("i-made-this-up")
  ).rejects.toThrow(
    "[API] Not recognised: i-made-this-up"
  );
});
```

`getData()` returns an Axios call and in this case an error is caught by `catch` and re-thrown.

```js
const getData = async (id) => {
  return await axios
    .get(`https://api.com/some/path?id=${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error?.response?.data?.message) {
        console.error(error) // Triggered the error
        throw new Error("[API] " + error.response.data.message);
      }

      throw error;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the env variables:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  db.init().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log('API lista por el puerto ', PORT)
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
} else {
  module.export = app
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was caused by asynchronous Redis connection still online. Just added **afterall** method to quit Redis and could see the log again.

Working on Typescript 4.4.2:

```
test("My Test", done => {
    let redisUtil: RedisUtil = new RedisUtil();
    let redisClient: Redis = redisUtil.redis_client();
    done();
});

afterAll(() => {
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to extend your timeout if you have a long running test using

`jest.setTimeout();`

In my case I'm paging through API calls and logging so it will extend after jest's default timeout, which is why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

```
Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
Attempted to log "Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one. ".
```

It was due to a missing `static` keyword. This code caused the issue:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  propTypes = {
    onDestroy: PropTypes.func,
  }
}
```

It should have been:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static propTypes = {
    onDestroy: PropTypes.func,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same warnings. However the fix is bit weird:

The jest unit test script import a function (which is not export from src/). After I added the `export` to the function to be tested. The error disappears.